# Render html in a cinder app

Tags: html, c++, webkit, cinder

I'm currently developing a game-like application in C++ using [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/)  (for Windows 7 or higher) where there is an editor where the user can create/edit game configurations. The user can select one of those configurations and play the game.
I've already built the game part of the application but I'd like to create the GUI of the app using html in the app's window in a webkit-like engine.
I looked up for embedded webkit technology and found out that is possible to run webkit inside one's app. But I don't know if it's possible to run it in a cinder app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a third party package of webkit, such as [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) (there is a 'cinderblock' add-on [here](https://github.com/paulhoux/Cinder-Awesomium) for it) or [chromium embedded](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef). There are other packages, too, such as [node-webkit](https://github.com/paulhoux/Cinder-Awesomium), or you could use a windows-specific web view. If you want to render the html UI on top of an opengl however, you'll want to make sure that whatever toolkit you use supports offscreen rendering (I know the first two I mentioned do and have been used for this purpose in cinder apps).

Comment: Thanks @rich.e I've been hacking with cinderblock for Awesomium but what happened is that the webkit version it uses is kind of old and it is rendering things oddly. I'll try to create my own simple widgets for the user interface if I struggle to much trying to use chromium embeded in a cinder app.